# Unhandled internal error. Java heap space when using EXPLAIN in pig

Tags: java, heap-memory, apache-pig

When I try to use the following statement

```
explain -brief A;
```

I got the following error

```
2013-02-06 19:18:34,250 [Low Memory Detector] INFO     org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - first memory handler call - Collection threshold init = 526123008(513792K) used = 349984528(341781K) committed = 699072512(682688K) max = 699072512(682688K)
2013-02-06 19:18:34,942 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Java heap space
```

I tried to increase the heap space size by adding option

```
-Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx4096m
```

but it didn't work. Any idea?

Thanks.
Dan

Comment: So what was the solution finally?

Answer (score 3):

1. Increase the PIG heap space using

   `export PIG_HEAPSIZE=4096`

ALTHOUGH, **if you're running the PIG in a Virtual Machine, make sure you have allocated more than 4GB (or whatever amount you want to set) of memory to the Virtual Machine**. Say if you've allocated `X` Gb's to the VM, then increasing the heap size more than `X` Gb's won't do anything.

2. ALSO, **it may be an issue with the PIG release you are using**.

Try using an older pig release. I  was getting the same reproducible issue with PIG-0.14.0 but not with [PIG-0.12.1](https://archive.apache.org/dist/pig/pig-0.12.1/)